# What is the font used for GNU documentation?

Tags: documentation, gnu, fonts

I am interested in learning how documentation for GNU related software is written, and am wondering what type of font is used in their PDF documentation? (for instance, [the GCC manual here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.1/gcc.pdf))

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The font is Donald Knuth's [Computer Modern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern). The documentation was no doubt created with [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) (or maybe even plain TeX). (Actually, these are both confirmed by the PDF metadata.)

(Edit: Poking around a bit more, it looks like, strictly speaking the documentation is created in a base format, which, thanks to [GNU texinfo](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/) is exported to a variety of formats, but the PDF format goes through TeX.)

If you want a high quality clone of Computer Modern in Open Type format, look at [the Latin Modern collection.](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern)

[TrueType versions of Computer Modern are also available.](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/ttf/)

Or you can just install LaTeX (see [TeXlive](http://tug.org/texlive/)) and get the real deal, with Type3 and Type1 fonts in a variety of encodings.

TeX is one of the earliest examples of free software, and Stallman even mentions it in [the GNU manifesto](http://www.gnu.org/gnu/manifesto.html): "We will use TeX as our text formatter ..."

Comment: Wonderful!! Thank you for the detailed answer. :)